# Need help for an algo

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I make a site where the color of the div is randomly generating compared to this array:

```js
let pastelColor = [
    'ffaacc','ffbbcc','ffcccc','ffddcc','ffeecc','ffffcc','ffaadd','ffbbdd','ffccdd','ffdddd','ffeedd','ffffdd',
    'ffaaee','ffbbee','ffccee','ffddee','ffeeee','ffffee','ffaaff','ffbbff','ffccff','ffddff','ffeeff','ffffff',
    'ccaaff','ccbbff','ccccff','ccddff','cceeff','ccffff','ccaaee','ccbbee','ccccee','ccddee','cceeee','ccffee',
    'ccaadd','ccbbdd','ccccdd','ccdddd','cceedd','ccffdd','ccaacc','ccbbcc','cccccc','ccddcc','cceecc','ccffcc'
]
```

I tried several Algo with Case Switch but the function took too much room, I was wondering in curiosity if an algo would be able to generate this array ?

Thank you in advance for those who answer

Comment: Please choose a title which will help others with the same issue, as SO is a repository for questions and answers rather than a personal help desk. Thank you

Comment: welcome! what effort have you made to solving the problem?

Comment: To generate this array, you would need to try to describe the pattern. It's hard to just guess based on looking at it. It would also be very helpful if you could share what you tried so far (and do please fix the title)

Comment: `console.log(\`hsla(${~~(360 * Math.random())},100%,70%,0.8)\`)`

Comment: *"the function took too much room"*: how so? There are libraries out there with thousands lines of code? Show us that code, and how it is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

> if an algo would be able to generate this array ?

Sure. If you need that array in that exact order:

```js
let pastelColor = Array.from("abcdef".repeat(8), (ch, i) => 
    (([a,...r]) => a+a+ch+ch+r[~~(i/6)%4].repeat(2))(i<24 ? "fcdef" : "cfedc")
);

console.log(pastelColor);
```

If you are not really interested in the array with color codes, but only in the generation of a random color from it, then:

```js
let pick = str => str[Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length)].repeat(2);
let pastelColor = pick("cf") + pick("abcdef") + pick("cdef");

console.log(pastelColor);
```

Comment: Or, to be absurdly pedantic about an array which is probably only used for random choosing, `Array.from("abcdef".repeat(8), (ch, i) => (i<24 ? "ff" : "cc") + ch.repeat(2) + (i < 24 ? "cdef" : "fedc")[~~(i/6)%4].repeat(2))`.  :-)

Comment: @Scott, thanks. Missed that specific order. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the array with the **converted hexadecimal color** with randomly generated integers **ranging from 0 to 255** like this:

```js
const getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

const getRandomColorUnit = () => {
    const color = getRandomInt(0, 256).toString(16);
    if (color.length < 2) return '0' + color;
    return color;
};

const getRandomColor = () => `#${getRandomColorUnit()}${getRandomColorUnit()}${getRandomColorUnit()}`;

const colors = new Array(100).fill(0).map(getRandomColor);

console.log(colors);
```